# Programmatically crop an image preserving exif with flutter

Tags: image, flutter, crop, exif

I need to crop programmatically an image (taken with the `camera` plugin), preserving as many metadata as possible (a.k.a. the image exif) of the original image.

The process should be:

- the user takes a picture with the main camera phone using our app;
- the app automatically crops the image, calculating a smaller rectangle inside the original image;
- finally, the image is resized to a fixed size, and uploaded to a server.

The requirement is that the final uploaded image has the same exif data of the original photo.

Currently, I use [this image dart library](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image) to perform crop and resize, but it seems not to preserving the original exif.

I implemented the following code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

Future<void> cropImage(
    String filePath, String destPath, int x, int y, int w, int h) async {
  Image _image = decodeJpg(await File(filePath).readAsBytes());
  Image _cropped = copyCrop(_image, x, y, w, h);
  Image _resized = copyResize(_cropped, width: 1120, height: 1120);
  await File(destPath).writeAsBytes(encodeJpg(_resized));
}
```

that correctly crop and riseze the image, but that doesn't preserve the exif.

Do you have any suggestion?